# Reference to std::iterator

Tags: c++, stdvector, c++98

I'd like to store a reference to a `std::vector::iterator`, but code such as the one pasted below doesn't compile, and using pointers will make things clumsy.

What is the best practice in such cases (C++98)?

P.S.: there is no risk of invalidating the iterator.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
int main(){
    std::vector<int> y;
    std::pair<int, std::vector<int>::iterator &> x = make_pair(5,y.begin());
};
```

Comment: your y is of type `vector<int>` but you are storing a reference of type edgeVec. Change to `std::pair<int, const std::vector<int>::iterator &> x` and it should compile.

Comment: @SamidhT: No, you cannot store a raw reference in a pair.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit _in C++98_ (you can in The Good C++ versions)

Answer (score 2):

```
std::pair<int, std::vector<int>::iterator &> x = make_pair(5,y.begin());
```

This won't compile, because `y.begin()` returns an rvalue, so `make_pair` returns a temporary of type `pair<int, vector<int>::iterator>`, and you can't create a `pair<int, vector<int>iterator&>` from that because it would bind a reference to a temporary.

Why do you want to anyway? It makes no sense to store a *reference* to a temporary iterator returned by `y.begin()`. What do you possibly hope to do with it? Why do you care about referring to *that particular* temporary from `y.begin()` as opposed to any other iterator value?

You could do it like this in C++11:

```
auto it = y.begin();  // an lvalue iterator
std::pair<int, std::vector<int>::iterator &> x = make_pair(5, it);
```

But now you need to keep `it` hanging around as long as you have `x`, or the reference becomes invalid, and again, why?

Finally, why are you bothering to use `make_pair` when you're not trying to deduce the types? You can just use the `pair` constructor:

```
auto it = y.begin();  // an lvalue iterator
std::pair<int, std::vector<int>::iterator &> x(5, it);
```

(Except that as LRiO points out, in C++98 you can't store references in `pair` anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

You can't store references directly because they are not assignable.

In C++11 you'd use a `std::reference_wrapper`.

You could just use a pointer. If you can't do that because your input is a temporary or will go out of scope then, well, that's a problem for a reference too. Then just **store the iterator by value**.

Comment: actually, there's a problem with using it by value.

`std::pair<int, EdgeVec::iterator> x = make_pair(5,y.begin());`

`/tmp/ccPHYBfi.o: In function '__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::deallocate(int*, unsigned long)':
m1.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE10deallocateEPim[__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::deallocate(int*, unsigned long)]+0x1c): undefined reference to 'operator delete(void*)'`

Comment: @Marat: Um, your compiler is broken

Comment: Probably tried to use `gcc` to link instead of `g++`

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to store a reference to an `std::vector::iterator`...

Why? An iterator refers to the element in the container (with some other intelligence) - why would you want to keep a reference to it, just store it by value; they are generally very "light" objects anyway.

> What is the best practice in such cases (C++98)?

Store it by value. The rvalue returned from `y.begin()` will need to be stored for the lifetime of the `pair` to avoid any dangling pointers or references; just store it by value.

```
std::pair<int, std::vector<int>::iterator> x(5, y.begin());
```